# What could cause a MySQL database to be extremely slow?

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

I'm trying to figure out why a MySQL database is abnormally slow on a live server. Deleting a row from a table (with only less than 100 rows) can take anywhere between 1 second and 20 seconds. I've checked the running processes and cannot see anything that would take out all the CPU or memory.

Also the website is not launched yet so there's just me on it.

In these conditions, what could be the reason for the database to be so slow? Is there any way to diagnose this kind of problem?

Comment: Probably belongs on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @JW웃, that was my first guess, so I've indexed all the columns that would make sense to be indexed, but it's still as slow. The 20 seconds query I got was after that (not saying indexes made it slower), on a small table with a simple "delete from table where id=123".

Comment: Even if there were no indexes defined, 100 rows wouldn;t be horrible unless you had some wildly inefficient delete query that depends on multiple nested in selects or something.

Comment: Are you deleting from a test web (on another server)? If so, try the `DELETE` directly on the MySQL server machine via the command line or Workbench and see if it's slow there too. It could just be the pipe between the two servers.

Comment: What database engine are you using? MYISAM? INNODB?

Comment: What about triggers? Maybe some infinite/very long loops happen?

Comment: Are you using the MySQL event scheduler? Are there any events fired?

Comment: adding indexes may actually SLOW DOWN the delete because the engine has to reorganize the indexes. so a table with 100 rows and 30 indexes may take forever to delete from due to all the indexes.

Comment: @Jocelyn, I'm using INNODB.

Comment: "My computer is slow. How to fix?" You need to give more information than that. Have you tuned your server? How much memory is allocated to InnoDB? How many rows are in the table you're modifying? What's going on in `SHOW PROCESSLIST`? Are you running out of disk IO?

Comment: @Jocelyn, I don't know about the MySQL event scheduler, I'm going to check that.

Comment: @xQbert, on that particular table, there's only one index, on the ID column.

Comment: Any chances there's swapping involved or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In these conditions, what could be the reason for the database to be so slow? Is there any way to diagnose this kind of problem?

Are you sure that it's the DB that is slow?

Connect to your server using the command line, launch mysql, and run a few sample queries from there. If it's plenty fast there (which it should, unless you're swapping like mad or have a gazillion funky triggers), you can safely eliminate SQL as the culprit. If not, there likely is a problem with your schema, your database configuration (does it have enough memory?) or your server (is the RAM broken?).

Another sources of slowness might be latency. Examples:

- Time needed to do a DNS lookup (e.g. on occasion, it's faster to connect to 127.0.0.1 than it is to connect to localhost)
- Lag due to the DB being located on a separate server (especially if the DB is at the other end of the world)
- Time needed to retrieve the results back from the DB, if blobs are involved.
- Dreadfully slow NSF:

  http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-fs/2013-April/017125.html
- etc.